# No output for console application in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

When I'm trying to load an image via Qt console application in Xcode everything ok, I can see my image in output:

```
Mat img = imread( "/Users/.../box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
imshow( "Source Image", img );
```

But if I try to output text:

```
std::cout << "Cannot load image" << " ";
```

there is nothing in output, I.e. I can't see the terminal window or another output console. How can I fix it?

Comment: The real question should be summarized to **When I try to print text with `std::cout` nothing is displayed!**, since this has nothing to do with OpenCV. Nothing at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::wcout to console window in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/stdwcout-to-console-window-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout` is typically line-buffered - add a `std::endl`:

```
std::cout << "Cannot load image" << std::endl;
```

Comment: anyway, there is no terminal window where i can see "Cannot load image"

Comment: You need to open up the console window in Xcode. In Xcode 3.x this is under the `Run` menu. If you're running in Terminal then output should just go to stdout in the Terminal window.